# Saving downloaded bitmaps through orientation changes

Tags: android, caching, screen-orientation

I have a ListView populated with a custom ArrayAdapter. Each row contains an image and some text downloaded both from the internet.

The problem is that changing the orientation of the device resets everything. The ListView is empty and it starts downloading text and images again!

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that Android re-creates the activity when the orientation changes. You can save/restore the state of the activity by overriding [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). Save what you deem is important about your activity so that it looks the same after orientation change.

The other option is to disable the re-creation of the activity by adding the following to your Android XML in your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

This option will also help you out if you're using `AsyncTask` to download the bitmaps. If the activity is re-created each time, you'll have to stop the download task and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the configuration changes yourself by overriding [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and onRestoreInstanceState. 
You can also make android NOT reStart your activity by adding

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in your manifest.

Also you may want to go through http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html for important tips on using bitmaps in android.

Comment: I can't disable the reStart, because I have different layouts for portrait and landscape in the layout and layout-land directories. If I disable reStart, the layout isn't upgraded...

Comment: How should I use onSaveInstanceState? AFAIK I can save only strings in the Bundle...

Comment: Use Bundle.putParcelable/Bundle.getParcelable .